# With NHibernate 2.1, how does one grab the first item in a collection using HQL to be used in the select clause?

Tags: nhibernate, collections, hql, indexer

Assume that I have a class Product:

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

and class Order:

```
public class Order
{
    public virtual float Amount { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

Assume they are mapped (using Fluent NHibernate) as follows:

```
public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
{
    public ProductMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasMany(x => x.Orders).OrderBy("created desc");
    }
}

public class OrderMap: ClassMap<Order>
{
    public OrderMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Amount);
        Map(x => x.Created);
    }
}
```

If I wanted to grab the `Name` of a `Product` as well as the `Amount` of the last `Order` (which, due to my mapped `OrderBy` clause, is the first) in an HQL statement, how would I go about it?  Something like this (for illustrative purposes):

```
select p.Name, p.Orders[0].Amount from Product p
```

I've attempted many variations on this, each with their own errors.

```
// Throws 'Property index does not exist in collection'
select p.Name, order.Amount from Product p join p.Orders as order where index(order) = 0

// Throws 'Antlr.Runtime.MismatchedTreeNodeException' on the brackets in p.Orders[0].
select p.Name, p.Orders[0] from Product P

// Throws 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'
select p.Name, p.Orders[0].Amount from Product p

// Works fine, but not what I want
select p.name, order.Amount from Product p join p.Orders as order
```

In this example, I could get away with using `SetMaxResults()`, but, in reality, the query is much more complex and returning many rows - so this won't do.

I feel like I'm missing something elementary here, so any help is appreciated.

Using:
 NHibernate 2.1.2.4000 and Fluent NHibernate 1.1.0.695

Comment: suggestion: think how you would do it in SQL.

Comment: I feel like there is a small problem with your mapping. Product class might not contain a List of Order, but vice via.

Comment: @Nathanphan - It was an example.  I am in no way using Products or Orders.  Forget the context, think of the exercise.  Thanks, though!

Comment: @Mauricio - in SQL, your options are limited to using TOP (or LIMIT, depending on the db) or specifying it in the where, having, or join clause.  Specifying it without knowing the last item involves a subselect, but not only is a sucky solution but an impossible solution in HQL, as HQL doesn't support limits on subqueries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this doesn't answer the question of whether or not you can pull an item by its index in a collection via HQL, but I did find a solution for my implementation:

I needed either the first or last item in a collection, and a subquery with min/max aggregate functions came to the rescue.  @Mauricio got me thinking a little deeper about alternatives in SQL and there came the answer:

```
select p.Name, order.Amount from Product p join p.Orders as order 
where order.Id = (select max(order2.Id) from Product p2 
join p2.Orders as order2 where p2.Id = p.Id)
```

It's not pretty, but it does the job.  Hope this helps someone else...